# Rails New Action not returning HTML on AJAX GET

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, controller, get

I'm working on a project where I upgraded the rails gem from 2.3.5 to 2.3.11 now I can't get the controller actions to return HTML via jQuery ajax get.  For example when I run this javascript: `$(function(){ $.get("/inbox/new"); });`

I can see in Firebug that the request was received with a status of 200.  I can see the request being rendered in my log. I can see that the CSRF token is being passed in the ajax get (but I don't know why it would matter anyways since it's a get and not a post).

I tried the respond to block 
   `respond_to do |format|
      format.html {render :layout => false, :action => :new}
    end`

The only way I can get the controller action to return anything (once again confirmed via Firebug) is by using `render :text => "whatever"` in the controller action.

Any ideas?!  Is there something different in rails 2.3.11 that I'm missing?!

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.  A very small but significant line of code screwed me up.  There was a content_for block in the new.html.haml view.  So view rendered on AJAX GET but the content didn't render because there was no layout specified. I can't believe I spent as many hours on this as I did.  Humbling experience.

Could I at least get some votes for my many lost hours of productivity?

Comment: We all feel for your many lost hours of productivity ...even years later.